# A non-absorbing state of a discrete Markov chain is recurrent if and only if the Green's function explodes at this state

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Let

- $E$ be an at most countable Polish space and $\mathcal E$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $E$
- $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a Markov chain with values $(E,\mathcal E)$, distributions $(\operatorname P_x)_{x\in E}$ and transition matrix $$p=\left(p(x,y)\right)_{x,y\in E}=\left(\operatorname P_x\left[X_1=y\right]\right)_{x,y\in E}$$
- $\tau_x^0:=0$ and $$\tau_x^k:=\inf\left\{n>\tau_x^{k-1}:X_n=x\right\}$$ for $x\in E$ and $k\in\mathbb N$ and $$\varrho(x,y):=\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^1<\infty\right]\color{blue}{=\operatorname P_x\left[\exists n\in\mathbb N:X_n=y\right]}$$
- $N(y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N_0}1_{\left\{X_n=y\right\}}$ be the number of visits of $X$ in $y\in E$

> $x\in E$ is called
>
> - **recurrent** $:\Leftrightarrow$ $\varrho(x,x)=1$
> - **absorbing** $:\Leftrightarrow$ $p(x,x)=1$

Now, let $$G(x,y):=\operatorname E_x\left[N(y)\right]\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E$$ be the **Green's function** of $X$.

> I want to show, that for a non-absorbing $x\in E$ $$x\text{ is recurrent }\Leftrightarrow\; G(x,x)=\infty$$

Using that $$\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^k<\infty\right]=\varrho(x,y)\varrho(y,y)^{k-1}\;\;\;\text{for all }x,y\in E\text{ and }k\in\mathbb N$$ we obtain

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G(x,y)&=&\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\operatorname P_x\left[N(y)\ge k\right]\\
&=&\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\operatorname P_x\left[\tau_y^k<\infty\right]+1_{\left\{x=y\right\}}\\
&=&\varrho(x,y)\sum_{k\in\mathbb N_0}\varrho(y,y)^k+1_{\left\{x=y\right\}}
&=&\frac{\varrho(x,y)}{1-\varrho(y,y)}+1_{\left\{x=y\right\}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $1/0:=\infty$, $0/0:=0$ and $0\cdot\infty:=0$. Especially, we've got $$G(y,y)=\frac 1{1-\varrho(y,y)}\tag 1$$

> **Question**:$\;\;\;$The statement follows immediately from the definitions and $(1)$. But why do we need to claim, that this statement only holds if $x$ is non-absorbing?

If $x$ is recurrent, then $(1)$ and $1/0=\infty$ yield $G(x,x)=\infty$. The same argument seems to yield the recurrence of $x$, whenever $G(x,x)=\infty$. So, what am I missing?

Comment: No such claim is being made; the absorbing case is being set aside (perhaps because it's trivial).  It's certainly true that if $x$ is absorbing then $x$  is recurrent and $G(x,x)=\infty$. The characterization of recurrent point by means of $G$ is valid for all states, absorbing or not.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I thought I would miss something, since the textbook I read states, that a "non-absorbing state $x$ is recurrent if and only if $G(x,x)=\infty$". After you comment, I think that this phrasing is somehow misleading.